# Blank screen on logon after update

Tags: 14.04

My new laptop is an ASUS X453M and I just installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. The installation was successful. After the first login, I just check the system info and press "Install update" to update. After restarting, my laptop just cannot login. It shows a blank screen and I still can hear the Ubuntu login sound but can not see anything rather than a blank screen. Maybe some issue with my graphic card. Please help.
Thanks.

PS: I want to note that the screen does not display anything, it's not really a blank screen.

Comment: @trgfdhry ygjhfgtgyjh: I'm sorry but just copy-pasting a link to pastebin is not an edit.  If you want to improve the post, also check the spelling&grammar, improve the readability, ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when the display server is not responding you can still obtain a non-graphical login screen by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Then you should be able to login, and you should look at the log file `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. Please paste here any error appearing in this file.

Comment: I tried to type Ctrl+Alt+F1 after hearing the Ubuntu logon sound but nothing happens

Comment: You should type this after everything has started, not just after you hear the sound. Another solution is to start in recovery mode: when the computer starts (at the very beginning, after only a few seconds), you press shift and/or esc, and the grub menu should show. Then you select the recovery option and you should be able to get a command-line session.

Comment: if using recovery mode, I can logon and access the GUI interface and I have updated the entire content of /var/log/Xorg.0.log as requested (at the first post)

Comment: What do you mean by "updated"? I was asking for you to paste here any error that you can find in that file...

Comment: because it's too long, I can not paste here so I copy it to Google docs and paste the link.

Comment: What is the output of 'dpkg --get-selections | grep ^xserver'

Answer (score 0):

Check if you've enough disk space, in a login screen by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. then login the system and type this command :

```
df -kh
```

If you've any 100% partition full that could block gnome starting.